# Trying to install a cluster, DHCP failing to start

Tags: centos, dhcp, ldap, cluster

Trying to install a linux cluster using [this tutorial](http://indico.ictp.it/event/a13229/session/22/contribution/87/material/0/0.pdf). I am running CentOS 6.3.

When I try to start DHCP with `service dhcpd start`, it fails. I've used `tail -f /var/log/messages` and `dhcpd -t`, but I don't fully understand the output. It appears that the error is

> Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
>
> Can't chown new lease file: operation not permitted

I never installed LDAP and I really don't understand where this is coming from. Am I misunderstanding the error message? If not, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP has support for searching configuration in an LDAP directory, but it needs configuration. That line just says that the configuration is absent and that therefore the DHCP server won't look for it. That's just a message, not an error, and certainly not the cause of your problem.

The next line tells you that dhcpd tries to change permissions on a particular file, which it isn't allowed to do. This can only happen if dhcpd is not running as root, which it should. Did you do the `service dhcpd start` as root? If not, do so.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to disable SELinux:

```
set SELINUX=disable
setenforce 0
```